# R BigRQuery error: unused argument (use_legacy_sql = FALSE)

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am having an issue with the BigRQuery package where it is not recognizing the `use_legacy_sql = FALSE` argument in `query_exec`. This is a new issue since it has been working swimmingly for me for the past few months. Has there been a change in the BigRQuery package?

The query I am running is:

```
sql_products <- "SELECT date(Date_Time), User_ID, Product, Country..." 

query_exec(sql_products, project= 'bigquery-project', use_legacy_sql = FALSE, max_pages = Inf)
```

The query runs successfully in Big Query with success with Legacy SQL off. I have also tried to switch out `use_legacy_sql = FALSE` for `useLegacySql = FALSE`. With no luck.

Is this a bug?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe check which version of the client you have installed? It should be use_legacy_sql based on the current state of [query.r](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/blob/master/R/query.r).

Comment: Elliot is right. The most recent version is `use_legacy_sql`. In the meantime, you could try prefixing your SQL with `#standardSQL` as a workaround.